# Allow space in regex when validating file

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've got a text box where I wanted to ensure some goods and bads out of it.

For instance good could include:

```
GoodString
GoodString88
99GoodString
```

Some bad things I did not want to include was:

```
Good*String
Good&String
```

But one thing I wanted to allow would be to allow spaces between words so this should of been good:

```
Good String
```

However my regex/js is stating this is NOT a good string - I want to allow it.  I'm using the test routine for this and **I'm as dumb as you can get with regexes**.  I don't know why I can never understand these things...

In any event my validation is as follows:

```
 var rx = /^[\w.-]+$/;
 if (!rx.test($("#MainContent_txtNewDocumentTitle").val())) {
    //code for bad string
 }else{
    //code for good string
 }
```

What can I do to this:

```
var rx = /^[\w.-]+$/;
```

Such that spaces are allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex instead to allow space only in middle (not at start/end):

```
var rx = /^[\w.-]+(?:[ \t]+[\w.-]+)*$/gm;
```

[RegEx Demo](http://%5E[%5Cw.-]+(?:%20%20[%5Cw.-]%20)*$)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^             # line start
[\w.-]+       # match 1 or more of a word character or DOT or hyphen
(?:           # start a non-capturing group
   [ \t]+     # match one or more space or tab
   [\w.-]+    # match 1 or more of a word character or DOT or hyphen
)*            # close the non-capturing group. * will allow 0 or more matches of group
$             # line end
/gm           # g for global and m for multiline matches
```

[RegEx Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info)

Comment: Let me try it because I had this before but ran into issues, ill try.

Comment: And this did it for me.  O magical one please tell me how you come up with regex's like this.  I despise them.

Comment: I will add some details and reference in answer.

Comment: What does the gm do ?

Comment: `g` for global and `m` for multiline matches to allow using anchors in each line.